# Using wrapAlll in order to have 6 elements multiplys html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you inspect the html of my demo you can see that, the `<div class="wrap fadeIn">` multiplies.
how ca I fix this?!

```
$('.items  .item', $container).each(function (i) {
            if (i % 6 == 0) {
                $(this).nextAll().andSelf().slice(0, 6).wrapAll('<div class="wrap fadeIn"></div>');
            }
            $(".grid-container").removeClass('four');
            $(".grid-container").addClass('six');
        });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JjWc/)

Comment: an `<li>` element is a valid child element of *only* a `<ul>` or `<ol>`; a `<div>` should *not* wrap an `<li>`.

Comment: yes u right, I've updated the Demo, but still doesn't sole my issue:-( have u got a clue of how to fix it?

Comment: Not at the moment, can you reduce your code to the absolute minimum (html, CSS and JavaScript) needed to demonstrate the problem, rather than the wall of JS your current demo shows? The only thing we need to see is your problem.

Comment: @David Thomas http://jsfiddle.net/8JjWc/  sure you right, I've modified the code

Comment: @DavidThomas whould u be able to help?